# Html5: "ondrop" event does not fire when I drop an item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

In my application I have the following html with js and stylesheet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Drag'n'Drop demo</title>

        <style>
            #dropArea{
                min-width:50%;
                min-height:800px;
                background-color:#FF00BB;
                float: left;
            }

            #imgArea {
                min-width:49%;
                min-height:800px;
                background-color:#0F0FBB;
                float: right;
            }

            #imgArea img {
                display:block;
                margin:5px;
            }

        </style>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
         integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
          var onDropCallback=function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("Droped")
          }

          var dragSrart=function(event){
            // alert("DragStarted")
            console.log("Drag Started");
          }

          var ondragoverCallback=function(event){
            var elem=event.target || event.srcElement;
            $(elem).css('border',"1px solid black");
          }

          var dragEndCallback=function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("Drag End HAppened");
            $("#dropArea").css('border',"none");
          }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dropArea" ondragover="ondragoverCallback(event)" ondrop="onDropCallback(event)" ></div>
        <div id="imgArea">
            <img draggable="true" ondragstart="dragSrart(event)" ondragend="dragEndCallback(event)" src="https://kazasou.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/g288.gif">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But for some reason even though the events `ondragstart` and `ondragend` gets fired I cannot figure out why the `drop` event does not fire at all. I have looked on https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_draganddrop.asp and on https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop but I cannot figure out how different is my code from the examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on: https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop you must `preventDefault` during on `dragover` event so the `ondragoverCallback` should have the following code:

```js
var ondragoverCallback=function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var elem=event.target || event.srcElement;
   $(elem).css('border',"1px solid black");
}
```